# Get Json Output with two select query in SQL Server

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, sql-server-json

I would like to output the results of a SELECT statement as a JSON object.

```
id    name        active  Status
1     Bob Jones   1       Active
2     John Smith  0       Inactive
```

I need return result like this:

```
{"Active"  :[{"id":1,"name":"Bob Jones" ,"active":1}],
 "InActive":[{"id":2,"name":"John Smith","active":0}]}
```

How to use the query?

I am using this code

```
DECLARE @JSONTierDetails AS TABLE (TierDetails VARCHAR(8000))

INSERT INTO @JSONTierDetails 
    SELECT
        (SELECT id, name, active 
         FROM MyTable 
         WHERE Status = 'Active' 
         FOR JSON PATH, INCLUDE_NULL_VALUES) TierDetails

SELECT TierDetails 
FROM @JSONTierDetails
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Which version of SQL Server are you using?

Answer (score 1):

```
-- Table definition
DECLARE @data TABLE(id int, [name] nvarchar(128), active bit, [status] nvarchar(30));

-- Insert test rows
INSERT @data VALUES(1, 'Bob Jones', 1, 'Active'), (2, 'John Smith', 0, 'Inactive');

-- Output
SELECT
    (SELECT id, name FROM @data WHERE active = 1 FOR JSON PATH) AS [Active],
    (SELECT id, name FROM @data WHERE active = 0 FOR JSON PATH) AS [Inactive]
FOR JSON PATH , WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER;
```

Answer (score 0):

Array wrappers and the property names for each JSON expression are needed for your case. Adding Array wrappers is not so hard but the property names is. `, ROOT(<property_name>)` after `FOR JSON PATH` might be used but that might be applied once and in static manner.

So, a Dynamic Query might be preferred, such as

```
DECLARE @JSONTierDetails NVARCHAR(MAX) = 
(
 SELECT 'SELECT ' + 
    STUFF((
            SELECT  N',(SELECT id, name, active 
                          FROM MyTable subT 
                         WHERE subT.status = ''' + status + N''' 
                           FOR JSON PATH
                       ) AS [' + status + N']' + CHAR(13) + '   '
              FROM MyTable t
            FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE).value('(./text())[1]','NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,1,'')
        + 'FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER' );

EXEC (@JSONTierDetails);
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=7f397b4fde635676a8bd8162f7a0b019)</kbd>

Answer (score -1):

see this page in microsoft site:
[JSON Data (SQL Server)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/json-data-sql-server)